# Visibility of TextView is set after scrolling and with bugs

Tags: java, android, listview, textview, android-arrayadapter

I created simple ListView with two TextViews - one for title (always visible), and one for note (not always visible). Problem is that visibility is set after scroll, and after many scrolls every note is visible.

Here is part of my adapter where I am setting visibility:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stop, null);

        TextView title   = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView request = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.request);

        holder.title   = title;
        holder.request = request;

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    Stop stop = list.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(stop.title());

    if (stop.request() == true)
        holder.request.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return view;
}
```

... and list element view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/request"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="(note)"
        android:textColor="#888888"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

If in my object (`Stop`) `request()` method returns true, note TextView should be visible, but some TextViews with false value are visible, and after e.g. 10 scrolls every hidden TextView is visible. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a little more research on what is convert view and how recycling work you would understand what happened in your situation.

For short and easy solution, do a

```
else
    holder.request.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have done research, but did not find anything what could resolve my problem, now I know what I should search in first place.